# How does MySQL lock each engine

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how does the locking happen for each of these engines:
- InnoDB
- MEMORY
- MERGE
- MyISAM

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-locking.html

Answer (score 0):

This MySQL documentation should spell it out for you:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-locking.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engines.html
may also help.